# Fresh Orchard Installation throwing Internal Server Error 500

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, orchardcms

I just finished installing Orchard on my Windows 2012 Server, the files are where they are suppose to be. I even copied the same files to my computer and run IIS Express through CMD and the Orchard worked perfectly locally.

I have MVC 4.0 installed on the server, the Application Pool is set to Integrated Mode and is running .NET 4.0. The Application Pool user also has permissions on the local folder where the Orchard files are located.

Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error page?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check App_data\logs folder.

Another idea is that you don't have mvc3 installed

Answer (score 0):

You can try Microsoft Web Platform Installer to apply recommended IIS settings. You can find it by using Start Menu Search Box.
Then just search for the "IIS Recommended Configuration" as this picture shows https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtlFY.jpg.